# C# Upload Chunking Sample Request

Tags: c#, api, chunking

Can some one please explain and possibly post a sample of an Upload function supporting Chunking please?

I have a parameter in a POST method which is expecting a Base64 string. I am using this with logic apps, and when content exceeds 100mb it automatically switches to chunking.

It would be great if some one can post a simple example how to implement this method.

Comment: HTTP 1.0 is stream, and HTTP 1.1 is Chunk mode.